# Want to iterate over array but increment count on an event

Tags: javascript, arrays, asynchronous, audio, iteration

```
saveBtn.addEventListener('click', async (e) => {
    if(!pressedKeys.length) return;
    let i = 0;
    while(i < pressedKeys.length){
        const audio = document.querySelector(`audio[data-key="${pressedKeys[i]}"]`);
        console.log(audio)
        audio.play();
        await audio.addEventListener('ended', (e) => { // await to test if it is async so it can be awaited but loop runs infinite and end event never called
            console.log('ended one audio', e);
            i++;
        })
    }
})
```

Wanted behaviour: Want to iterate over array on audio ended event is there a way.. If there, please help me out ..
Pre thanks :)

Comment: What language is it? Looks like java, but *if(!pressedKeys.length) * does not make sense in java proper.

Comment: Incrementing over an array doing what? On each iteration what is doing what? `pressedKeys` isn't even defined (ex. `let pressedKeys = [*A series of primatives and/or objects*]` .